# Azure powershell - Get list of VMs with size

Tags: azure, powershell

Trying to get a basic powershell script to retrieve the VM name and VM size.

I can run the following command:

```
Get-AzureRMVM
```

This shows a list of VMs with "name" and "VMSize" columns, among others.  I'm just trying to display those two columns, so I have this:

```
[array]$VMs = Get-AzureRMVm 

foreach ($VM in $VMs)
 {
Write-Output "VM: $($VM.Name)"
Write-Output "VM Size: $($VM.VmSize)"
 }
```

For some reason while the VM name is showing up, the size is not.
Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VmSize is pulled from HardwareProfile. Try using `$VM.HardwareProfile.VMSize`

[Reference.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/05/31/retrieve-azure-resource-manager-virtual-machine-properties-by-using-powershell-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Get-AzComputeResourceSku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azcomputeresourcesku) module

Sample script:

```
Get-AzComputeResourceSku 
| Where-Object { $_.ResourceType.Contains("virtualMachines") } 
| select size, name
```